# Why is my Android phone sending data through an unknown server?

Tags: android, security, networking, dns, wifi

I've been creating an app to learn how Android works and just playing around with various features like the sensors, SMS listeners, phone listeners, wifi listeners, etc.

I recently added a bit of code from the *Android Volley* library to send a request to my website every time it connects to a wifi network (I don't have a cellular data plan).

It sends a `GET request` to a very sparse text file that returns back:

```
hello
```

The odd thing is that after connecting to open public wifi networks, oftentimes the response that the phone gets from this same request will be:

```
<html>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<script language="javascript">
document.location.href="http://den-80202-7200.localdomain:8000/index.php?zone=pms&redurl=http://my-personal-server.com/hello
</script>
</html>
```

Which is really strange to me, as it will return this even the next day, connecting to other networks, connecting to my secured network at home, etc.

And I have no idea what this URL is:

```
http://den-80202-7200.localdomain:8000
```

It appears to me, (still learning about how this all works), that my phone is sending my GET request to my website, but somehow my website is returning back this possibly infected response, which, if I was in a browser may harm me. Maybe my website server is infected with something?

Or, my phone has malware that is sending all my requests through this unknown server?

Is that what is going on? How to prevent my phone from keep sending requests through this unknown server? I did a virus scan and it comes up clean. Is there a way to flush the phone's DNS cache or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in general it's good to be suspicious about hijacked or modified requests on open wifi networks, in this case it appears to be expected behavior for public wifi networks.

Specifically, many public wifi networks require authentication either for paid access or to accept terms of service.  To accomplish this, they will often intercept HTTP requests from unauthenticated clients and return a response which redirects them to a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

Since .localdomain is not a valid TLD, this URL will not work outside a network without a local DNS entry for it.  This appears similar to the use of [.local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) as a reserved [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) for local-network only DNS entries.  Again, this is indicative of public wifi networks using .localdomain URLs to redirect to a locally hosted captive portal.

Note also that the redirect URL has the parameter "redurl=http://my-personal-server.com/hello", this specifies the URL that you'll be redirected to after your authenticate.  As expected, this was the original URL you requested.

**NOTE:** As for this showing up on your private wifi networks afterwards, I suspect this is a caching issue.  Again, since .localdomain isn't a valid [TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) the request to "http://den-80202-7200.localdomain:8000" will fail outside of the public wifi network with support for this specific DNS entry.

Comment: This seems like it is a more helpful answer and sheds more light on the issue. I think this may be more relevant to my situation, especially the explanation of the localdomain and the captive portal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your system is infected with Malware or SpyBots.

Check out below link:

http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8000

Comment: That is a great possible explanation. Do you think it is my phone that is probably infected, or my web server?

Comment: Could this possibly be a poisoned-DNS attack? When I connect to a bad open network, that has an infected DNS server, it may send me to the bad address when I try to access my website?